# Is it possible to prevent jekyll from using subdirectories as categories

Tags: jekyll

I'm creating a personal blog with Jekyll just to organize personal notes.

I developed the blog to have as many sub-blogs as my notes require.

I just noticed that all the posts that are in a different directory other than `_posts` get that directory as a category. Is there a way to remove this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing a post in `_posts/folder1` : no "*categories*" set.

Placing a post in a `folder2/_posts` : attribution of a **folder2** "*categories*".

Note that we talk about the **categories** variable and not **category** which is not the same.